# Pass value from javascript to contained php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, database

Trying to pass a variable from javascript to php to be inserted in a database. This has to be done without refreshing the page etc. The values come directly from the js and are not in the html. Here is a clip from my code:

```
<script>
    ...
    // Variables to submit, for now assume they have values   
    var username;
    var filename;
    var chart_data;
    <?php
        $query = "INSERT INTO table_name(userName,data,file_name) 
        VALUES('/*the username */','/*the chart_data*/','/*the filename*/')";
        $res = mysql_query($query);
    ?>
    ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send the values by an http request, and receive them in `REQUEST` in PHP.
You can achieve this easily by [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 0):

Use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) to fulfill your purpose. Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript + XML) is not a technology in itself, but a group of technologies branded together, including: HTML or XHTML, Cascading Style Sheets, JavaScript, The Document Object Model, XML, XSLT, and most importantly the XMLHttpRequest object. XML nowadays is not used anymore, the main data model is [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)(Javascript Object Notation), because countless facilities.

PS: If your routine it's too basic, avoid libraries like jQuery or frameworks, it's unnecessary. You will load a bunch of code to do only a simple AJAX? Common... We need to take the raw codes more frequently, guys, jQuery helps crossbrowser issues and accelerates some implementations, but it's important to show solutions in pure javascript to enforce simplicity on the community.

```
<script>
    ...
    // Variables to submit, for now assume they have values   
    var username;
    var filename;
    var chart_data;
    <script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc() {

    var data = {
    username: username, //or the values itself
    filename: filename,
    chart_data: chart_data
};
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE ) {
           if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
               alert('ok');
           }
           else if (xmlhttp.status == 400) {
              alert('There was an error 400');
           }
           else {
               alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
           }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "yourpage.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(data);
}
//call wherever you want, with the needed variables loaded
loadXMLDoc();

// or the simplest ajax ever without function formed
var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", 'yourfile.php');
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
            console.log('Response: ' + xmlhttp.responseText );
        }else{
            console.log('Error: ' + xmlhttp.statusText )
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.send(data);
    </script> 
        <?php
           if (isset($_POST)){
            $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
            $query = "INSERT INTO table_name(userName,data,file_name) 
            VALUES("$data->username","$data->chart_data","$data->filename")";
            $res = mysql_query($query);
         }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript is in your browser; php is server side.

Your browser can't do the php.  So what needs to happen is:

1. Create an html form and have the javascript fill in the values,
2. Submit to a PHP page that saves to the database,
3. Redirect to your next page

--or--

Use AJAX to submit to a php script that saves to the database.  You can do this with native javascript; but it would probably be easier to look into JQuery.  Give that a lookover and try it out. It's well documented, and you should be able to figure it out from the JQuery documentation.

Also, for your database activity, you'll want to use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Too slow typing... what Carlos said.